# Assetic ignores output file and only generate one file

Tags: symfony, assetic, symfony-2.5

I have some templates containing following asset part with different input files and output file:

```
{% javascripts
    '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/assets/js/jquery.plugin.min.js'
    '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/assets/js/jquery.countdown.js'
    output='js/compiled/jquery.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

In development environment everything works fine.
In production environment only one file is generated and the ouput file name is ignored. Furthermore it loads the wrong content in the wrong template.

One template contains normally the path to the js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/assets/js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/assets/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

The other template gets the link to the wrong combined js file (it is the jquery combined file):

```
<script src="/js/700bfe8.js"></script>
```

There is no special configuration for assetic in the config.yml, just added the bundle. The remaining stuff is based on Symfony Standard Edition.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really explain what was the solution, but it works for me, now.

I have changed the path from *Resources/assets* to *Resources/public* and removed all generated stuff from assetic and cleared the cache.

After it the dump worked correctly.